# Group work states into whole 15 minutes interval or nearest minute

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have some data that needs to be grouped by AgentID, Workstate and 15 minutes intervals or nearest minute if a workstate changes within a 15 minute interval.

Data is created when my agents go from one work state to another as shown below:

```
DateTime                | AgentID | Workstate
---------------------------------------------------------------
2017-03-01 09:55:00     | RAR     | Customer Service
---------------------------------------------------------------
2017-03-01 10:18:00     | RAR     | Retention
---------------------------------------------------------------
2017-03-01 10:30:00     | RAR     | Customer Service
---------------------------------------------------------------
2017-03-01 10:45:00     | RAR     | Mail
---------------------------------------------------------------
2017-03-01 11:00:00     | RAR     | Customer Service
---------------------------------------------------------------
2017-03-01 11:53:00     | RAR     | Logged out
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

These data should be grouped by 15 minutes interval or if a states changes within a 15 minute interval use nearest minute like this:

```
DateTime Start      | DateTime End        | AgentID | Workstate
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-03-01 09:55:00 | 2017-03-01 10:00:00 | RAR     | Customer Service
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-03-01 10:00:00 | 2017-03-01 10:15:00 | RAR     | Customer Service
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-03-01 10:15:00 | 2017-03-01 10:18:00 | RAR     | Customer Service
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-03-01 10:18:00 | 2017-03-01 10:30:00 | RAR     | Retention
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-03-01 10:30:00 | 2017-03-01 10:45:00 | RAR     | Customer Service
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-03-01 10:45:00 | 2017-03-01 11:00:00 | RAR     | Mail
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-03-01 11:00:00 | 2017-03-01 11:15:00 | RAR     | Customer Service
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-03-01 11:15:00 | 2017-03-01 11:30:00 | RAR     | Customer Service
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-03-01 11:30:00 | 2017-03-01 11:45:00 | RAR     | Customer Service
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-03-01 11:45:00 | 2017-03-01 11:53:00 | RAR     | Customer Service
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
2017-03-01 11:53:00 | 2017-03-01 12:00:00 | RAR     | Logged out
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I hope the description above makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Try This, showing exact result as expected.

```
    DECLARE @StartTime  VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @EndTime    VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @MM         VARCHAR(5)
DECLARE @StartTimeBucket    VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @ENDTimeBucket      VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @Cnt        INT
CREATE TABLE #Bucket (ID INT,StrtTime DATETIME,EndTime DATETIME,Rec_Cnt INT)
Create table #SampleData1 
(
   [Datetime] datetime,
   AgentID varchar(10),
   Workstate varchar(500),
   Row_Num  Int
)
INSERT INTO #SampleData1 (AgentID,Workstate,[Datetime],Row_Num)
Select AgentId,Workstate,[Datetime],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER( Partition by AgentId order by Workstate)     
From SampleData
SET @StartTime = (SELECT MIN([Datetime]) FROM SampleData)
SET @EndTime = (SELECT MAX([Datetime]) FROM SampleData)
SET @MM = (SELECT SUBSTRING(@StartTime,16,2))
SET @StartTimeBucket = (SELECT CASE WHEN @MM BETWEEN 1 AND 15 THEN DATEADD(MINUTE,(15-@MM),@StartTime) WHEN @MM BETWEEN 15 AND 30 THEN DATEADD(MINUTE,(30-@MM),@StartTime) WHEN @MM BETWEEN 30 AND 45 THEN DATEADD(MINUTE,(45-@MM),@StartTime) WHEN @MM BETWEEN 45 AND 60 THEN DATEADD(MINUTE,(60-@MM),@StartTime) END)
SET @MM = (SELECT SUBSTRING(@EndTime,16,2))
SET @EndTimeBucket = (SELECT CASE WHEN @MM BETWEEN 1 AND 15 THEN DATEADD(MINUTE,(15-@MM),@EndTime) WHEN @MM BETWEEN 15 AND 30 THEN DATEADD(MINUTE,(30-@MM),@EndTime) WHEN @MM BETWEEN 30 AND 45 THEN DATEADD(MINUTE,(45-@MM),@EndTime) WHEN @MM BETWEEN 45 AND 60 THEN DATEADD(MINUTE,(60-@MM),@EndTime) END)
SET @Cnt = (SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE,@StartTimeBucket,@EndTimeBucket)/15 +1)
WHILE (@Cnt > 0)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO #Bucket (ID,StrtTime,EndTime,Rec_Cnt)
VALUES (@Cnt,DATEADD(Minute,-15,@EndTimeBucket),@EndTimeBucket,(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM SampleData WHERE [Datetime] BETWEEN DATEADD(Minute,-15,@EndTimeBucket) AND @EndTimeBucket))
SET @Cnt = @Cnt - 1
SET @EndTimeBucket = DATEADD(Minute,-15,@EndTimeBucket)
END

Select *
FROM
(
Select (CASE WHEN [DateTime] IS NOT NULL THEN [DateTime] ELSE StrtTime END) AS [DateTime Start],
        EndTime AS [DateTime End],--AgentID,id,LAG (AgentID) OVER (ORDER BY ID),LAG (AgentID,2) OVER (ORDER BY ID),
        (CASE WHEN AgentID IS NULL AND LAG (AgentID) OVER (ORDER BY ID) IS NULL THEN LAG (AgentID,2) OVER (ORDER BY ID) WHEN AgentID IS NULL THEN LAG (AgentID) OVER (ORDER BY ID) ELSE AgentID END) AS AgentID,
        (CASE WHEN Workstate IS NULL AND LAG (Workstate,1) OVER (ORDER BY ID) IS NULL THEN LAG (Workstate,2) OVER (ORDER BY ID) WHEN Workstate IS NULL THEN LAG (Workstate,1) OVER (ORDER BY ID) ELSE Workstate END) AS  Workstate
FROM (
    select * 
    from #SampleData1 INNER join #Bucket 
    ON [Datetime] >= StrtTime and [Datetime] <= EndTime
    UNION 
    SELECT NULL As [DateTime],NULL As AgentID,NULL As Workstate, Null As Row_Num,*
    FROM #Bucket WHERE Rec_Cnt = 0
    ) Final
WHERE ISNULL([DateTime],'') <> EndTime 

UNION
Select StrtTime AS [DateTime Start],
        [DateTime] AS [DateTime End],
        LAG (AgentID,1,NULL) OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS AgentID,
        LAG (Workstate,1,NULL) OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS  Workstate
FROM (
    select * 
    from #SampleData1 INNER join #Bucket 
    ON [Datetime] >= StrtTime and [Datetime] <= EndTime
    --order by Id
    UNION 
    SELECT NULL As [DateTime],NULL As AgentID,NULL As Workstate, Null As Row_Num,*
    FROM #Bucket WHERE Rec_Cnt = 0
    ) Final
WHERE StrtTime < [Datetime] and ISNULL([DateTime],'') <> EndTime 
) Final_Result
WHERE AgentID IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [recursive CTE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx) and [CROSS APPLY](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1958/sql-server-cross-apply-and-outer-apply/) like this

```
DECLARE @SampleData AS TABLE
(
   [Datetime] datetime,
   AgentID varchar(10),
   Workstate varchar(500)
)

INSERT INTO @SampleData
VALUES
('2017-03-01 09:55:00','RAR','Customer Service'),
('2017-03-01 10:18:00','RAR','Retention'),
('2017-03-01 10:30:00','RAR','Customer Service'),
('2017-03-01 10:45:00','RAR','Mail'),
('2017-03-01 11:00:00','RAR','Customer Service'),
('2017-03-01 11:53:00','RAR','Logged out')

DECLARE @MinDate datetime =  (SELECT min(sd.[Datetime]) FROM @SampleData sd)
DECLARE @MaxDate datetime =  (SELECT max(sd.[Datetime]) FROM @SampleData sd)

;WITH temp AS
(
   SELECT CAST('2017-03-01 00:00:00' AS datetime)  AS IntervalDate 

   UNION ALL

   SELECT dateadd(minute,15, t.IntervalDate) AS IntervalDate 
   FROM temp t
   WHERE t.IntervalDate < @MaxDate
)
SELECT 
      CASE WHEN sd.Datetime < cr.IntervalDate THEN sd.Datetime ELSE cr.IntervalDate END AS [Datetime Start],
      CASE WHEN sd.Datetime < cr.IntervalDate THEN cr.IntervalDate ELSE sd.Datetime END AS [Datetime End],
      sd.AgentID, 
      sd.Workstate
FROM @SampleData sd
CROSS APPLY
(
   SELECT * 
   FROM temp t
   WHERE      t.IntervalDate >= @MinDate
         AND (  
                datediff(minute, t.IntervalDate, sd.Datetime) BETWEEN 0 AND 15
                OR datediff(minute, sd.Datetime, t.IntervalDate) BETWEEN 0 AND 15
            )

) cr
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Demo link: [Rextester](http://rextester.com/YRXP97460)

Answer (score 0):

Definitely a hard question to solve, but I have found query to solve it. It does give your disered output.

A little bit of explanation, I used 2 common table expressions. In the first I calculate the next and the prev intervals of all time points. Next I group them per starttimepoint and take the smallest endpoint. Then with an outer apply I fill up the null values of the agentid and workstate

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (Dt DATETIME, AgentId VARCHAR(255), WorkState VARCHAR(255))
INSERT INTO @t VALUES
('2017-03-01 09:55:00','RAR','Customer Service'),
('2017-03-01 10:18:00','RAR','Retention'),
('2017-03-01 10:30:00','RAR','Customer Service'),
('2017-03-01 10:45:00','RAR','Mail'),
('2017-03-01 11:00:00','RAR','Customer Service'),
('2017-03-01 11:53:00','RAR','Logged out')

DECLARE @d TABLE (DateTimes DATETIME)
INSERT INTO @d VALUES
('2017-03-01 10:00:00'),
('2017-03-01 10:15:00'),
('2017-03-01 10:30:00'),
('2017-03-01 10:45:00'),
('2017-03-01 11:00:00'),
('2017-03-01 11:15:00'),
('2017-03-01 11:30:00'),
('2017-03-01 11:45:00'),
('2017-03-01 12:00:00'),
('2017-03-01 12:15:00'),
('2017-03-01 12:30:00')

;With mCte AS (
SELECT t.Dt, CASE WHEN DATEPART(MINUTE, t.Dt) = 0 OR DATEPART(MINUTE, t.Dt) = 15 OR DATEPART(MINUTE, t.Dt) = 30 OR DATEPART(MINUTE, t.Dt) = 45 
              THEN CASE WHEN DATEPART(MINUTE, t.Dt) = 0 THEN DATEADD(MINUTE,15, t.Dt)
                        WHEN DATEPART(MINUTE, t.Dt) = 15 THEN DATEADD(MINUTE,15, t.Dt)
                        WHEN DATEPART(MINUTE, t.Dt) = 30 THEN DATEADD(MINUTE,15, t.Dt)
                        WHEN DATEPART(MINUTE, t.Dt) = 45 THEN DATEADD(MINUTE,15, t.Dt)
                    END
              ELSE CASE WHEN ABS(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, t.Dt) + 1, 0), t.dt)) < 15 
                        THEN DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, t.Dt) + 1, 0)
                  WHEN ABS(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, t.Dt) + 1, 0), t.dt)) < 30
                        THEN DATEADD(MINUTE, 45 - DATEPART(MINUTE,t.DT), t.DT)
                  WHEN ABS(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, t.Dt) + 1, 0), t.dt)) < 45
                        THEN DATEADD(MINUTE, 30 - DATEPART(MINUTE,t.DT), t.DT)
                  WHEN ABS(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, DATEADD(HOUR, DATEDIFF(HOUR, 0, t.Dt) + 1, 0), t.dt)) < 60
                        THEN DATEADD(MINUTE, 15 - DATEPART(MINUTE,t.DT), t.DT)
            END
        END AS Interval, t.AgentId, t.WorkState
FROM    @t AS t 

UNION ALL

SELECT  CASE WHEN ISNULL(ABS(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, t.DT, LAG(t.Dt) OVER (ORDER BY t.DT))), 0) = 0
        THEN CASE WHEN DATEPART(MINUTE, t.Dt) > 45 THEN DATEADD(MINUTE, 45 - DATEPART(MINUTE,t.DT), t.DT)
                WHEN DATEPART(MINUTE, t.Dt) > 30 THEN DATEADD(MINUTE, 30 - DATEPART(MINUTE,t.DT), t.DT)
                WHEN DATEPART(MINUTE, t.Dt) > 15 THEN DATEADD(MINUTE, 15 - DATEPART(MINUTE,t.DT), t.DT)
                WHEN DATEPART(MINUTE, t.Dt) > 0 THEN DATEADD(MINUTE, 0 - DATEPART(MINUTE,t.DT), t.DT)
        END
        ELSE CASE
         WHEN ISNULL(ABS(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, t.DT, LAG(t.Dt) OVER (ORDER BY t.DT))), 0) > 45 
        THEN DATEADD(MINUTE, 45 - DATEPART(MINUTE,t.DT), t.DT)
         WHEN ISNULL(ABS(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, t.DT, LAG(t.Dt) OVER (ORDER BY t.DT))), 0) > 30 
        THEN DATEADD(MINUTE, 30 - DATEPART(MINUTE,t.DT), t.DT)
         WHEN ISNULL(ABS(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, t.DT, LAG(t.Dt) OVER (ORDER BY t.DT))), 0) > 15 
        THEN DATEADD(MINUTE, 15 - DATEPART(MINUTE,t.DT), t.DT)
        ELSE DATEADD(MINUTE,  -15 , t.Dt)
        END
    END AS Interval, t.Dt, LAG(t.AgentId) OVER(ORDER BY Dt) AS AgentId, LAG(t.WorkState) OVER(ORDER BY Dt) AS WorkState

FROM    @t AS t

UNION ALL

SELECT  d.DateTimes, DATEADD(MINUTE, 15, d.DateTimes) AS NextInterval, NULL, NULL
FROM    @d AS d 
), rmCte AS (
SELECT Dt, MIN(Interval) AS EndTime, MIN(AgentId) AS AgentId, MIN(WorkState) AS WorkState
FROM mCte
GROUP BY Dt)

SELECT f.Dt, f.EndTime, ISNULL(f.AgentId, f2.AgentId) AS AgentId, ISNULL(f.WorkState, f2.WorkState) AS WorkState
FROM rmCte AS f OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP 1 f2.*
    FROM rmCte AS f2
    WHERE f2.Dt >= f.Dt AND f2.EndTime <= f2.EndTime AND AgentId IS NOT NULL
) f2
```

Result

```
StartTime                EndTime                  AgentId  WorkState
2017-03-01 09:45:00.000  2017-03-01 09:55:00.000  RAR      Customer Service
2017-03-01 09:55:00.000  2017-03-01 10:00:00.000  RAR      Customer Service
2017-03-01 10:00:00.000  2017-03-01 10:15:00.000  RAR      Customer Service
2017-03-01 10:15:00.000  2017-03-01 10:18:00.000  RAR      Customer Service
2017-03-01 10:18:00.000  2017-03-01 10:30:00.000  RAR      Retention
2017-03-01 10:30:00.000  2017-03-01 10:45:00.000  RAR      Customer Service
2017-03-01 10:45:00.000  2017-03-01 11:00:00.000  RAR      Mail
2017-03-01 11:00:00.000  2017-03-01 11:15:00.000  RAR      Customer Service
2017-03-01 11:15:00.000  2017-03-01 11:30:00.000  RAR      Customer Service
2017-03-01 11:30:00.000  2017-03-01 11:45:00.000  RAR      Customer Service
2017-03-01 11:45:00.000  2017-03-01 11:53:00.000  RAR      Customer Service
2017-03-01 11:53:00.000  2017-03-01 12:00:00.000  RAR      Logged out
2017-03-01 12:00:00.000  2017-03-01 12:15:00.000  NULL     NULL
2017-03-01 12:15:00.000  2017-03-01 12:30:00.000  NULL     NULL
2017-03-01 12:30:00.000  2017-03-01 12:45:00.000  NULL     NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one:

```
Create table #SampleData 
(
   [Datetime] datetime,
   AgentID varchar(10),
   Workstate varchar(500)
)

INSERT INTO #SampleData
VALUES ('2017-03-01 09:55:00','RAR','Customer Service'), ('2017-03-01 10:18:00','RAR','Retention'),
('2017-03-01 10:30:00','RAR','Customer Service'), ('2017-03-01 10:45:00','RAR','Mail'),
('2017-03-01 11:00:00','RAR','Customer Service'), ('2017-03-01 11:53:00','RAR','Logged out')

declare @startTrns datetime =  convert(datetime,convert(date, (select min ([datetime]) from #SampleData)))
declare @endTrns datetime =  convert(datetime,(select max ([datetime]) from #SampleData))

select [datetime], AgentID, Workstate, case when [next_datetime] is null then 
            case when datepart(minute, [datetime]) <= 15 then dateadd(minute, (15 - datepart(minute, [datetime])), [datetime])
                 when datepart(minute, [datetime]) <= 30 then dateadd(minute, (30 - datepart(minute, [datetime])), [datetime])
                 when datepart(minute, [datetime]) <= 45 then dateadd(minute, (45 - datepart(minute, [datetime])), [datetime])
                 when datepart(minute, [datetime]) <= 60 then dateadd(minute, (60 - datepart(minute, [datetime])), [datetime])
            end
         else [next_datetime] end as [next_datetime]
INTO #SampleData1
from (
    select [datetime], LEAD([datetime],1,null) over (order by [datetime]) as [next_datetime], 
    AgentID, Workstate
    from #SampleData
)a

;with time_interval as (
    select @startTrns as [timeinterval]
    union all
    select dateadd(minute, 15, [timeinterval]) from time_interval
    where [timeinterval] < @endTrns
)

select [timeinterval], isnull(LEAD([timeinterval],1,null) over (order by [timeinterval]), dateadd(minute, 15, [timeinterval])) as [next_timeinterval]
into #time_intvl
from time_interval


select AgentID, Workstate, [datetime], [timeinterval], [next_timeinterval], [next_datetime], row_number() over (order by [datetime]) as rnk
into #SampleData2
from (
    select sd1.AgentID, sd1.Workstate, sd1.[datetime], sd1.[next_datetime], tim.[timeinterval], tim. [next_timeinterval]
    from #SampleData1 sd1
    inner join #time_intvl tim on tim.[timeinterval] between sd1.[datetime] and sd1.[next_datetime]
    union all
    select sd2.AgentID, sd2.Workstate, sd2.[datetime], sd2.[next_datetime], tim2.[timeinterval], tim2.[next_timeinterval]
    from #SampleData1 sd2
    inner join #time_intvl tim2 on tim2.[timeinterval] < sd2.[next_datetime] and sd2.[next_datetime] >= tim2.[next_timeinterval]
            and sd2.[datetime] < tim2.[timeinterval]
)b

select distinct [DateTime Start], [DateTime End], AgentID, Workstate 
from (
    select AgentID, Workstate,
           case when rnk <> 1 then 
                case when [timeinterval] < [next_datetime] then [timeinterval] else [datetime] end
           else [datetime] end as [DateTime Start],
           case when rnk <> 1 then 
                case when [next_datetime] < [next_timeinterval] then [next_datetime] else [next_timeinterval] end
           else [timeinterval] end as [DateTime End]
    from #SampleData2
)temp
order by [DateTime Start]

drop table #SampleData
drop table #SampleData1
drop table #SampleData2
drop table #time_intvl
```

[image]